# Sticky element on top of other elements without leaving container

Tags: html, css, sticky

I have a site I need to make it where as you scroll down the page a phone sticks in place, in the center, and the  phone content swaps as you scroll until you reach a certain point (such as the footer). The issue I'm running into is keeping it within the scrollable area since the only way I could figure out how to overlay it is with position:absolute. Adding that, however, means it's no longer "sticky" within the container. It pops out.

Here's an example (you can run a demo below): https://codepen.io/oscargodson/pen/OJXJGRL

Screenshots:

Page load

[image]

Scrolling down (notice its centered still and overlaying on top of everything else)

[image]

The green border is the yellow square's (phone image in real life) container/parent. Notice how it comes out.

[image]

I'd really rather not use JS if at all possible but if it's the only way that's fine.

```css
.panel-wrapper {
  border: 5px solid chartreuse;
  position: relative;
}

.panel {
  height: 100vh;
}

.panel-1 { background: aqua; }
.panel-2 { background: blue; }
.panel-3 { background: darkblue; }

.sticky-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  background: transparent;
  top: calc(100vh/2 - 613px/2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 3;
}

.sticky-element {
  width: 315px;
  height: 613px;
  background: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

footer {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 250px 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="panel-wrapper">
    <div class="sticky-wrapper">
      <div class="sticky-element"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-1"></div>
    <div class="panel panel-2"></div>
    <div class="panel panel-3"></div>
  </div>
  <footer>
     Should not overlap here!
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: If you remove `position: absolute` from `.sticky-element` it won't overlap. If you add a `margin-bottom: calc(100vh/2 - 613px/2);` to your `.sticky-wrapper` it might do what yo'ure expecting.

Comment: @AmauryHanser from what I see, removing absolute gives sticky-element a height which leads to a big white bar at the top. It keeps it within, but it doesn't overlay on the panels (afaik)

Comment: Use position: fixed

Comment: @OscarGodson I've missed that sorry, then maybe you can do as I said but add `float: left` to `.sticky-wrapper`

Comment: @SteveTomlin position:fixed would work the exact way I don't want it to unless I'm misunderstanding? Its mostly working like position:fixed now is the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `position:absolute` and make the sticky container `float:left`

```css
.panel-wrapper {
  border: 5px solid chartreuse;
  position: relative;
}

.panel {
  height: 100vh;
}

.panel-1 { background: aqua; }
.panel-2 { background: blue; }
.panel-3 { background: darkblue; }

.sticky-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  background: transparent;
  top: calc(100vh/2 - 613px/2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 3;
  float:left; /* added */
}

.sticky-element {
  width: 315px;
  height: 613px;
  background: yellow;
  top: 0;
}

footer {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 250px 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="panel-wrapper">
    <div class="sticky-wrapper">
      <div class="sticky-element"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-1"></div>
    <div class="panel panel-2"></div>
    <div class="panel panel-3"></div>
  </div>
  <footer>
     Should not overlap here!
  </footer>
</div>
```

If you will have content, consider `shape-outisde` trick so you can also overlap text:

```css
.panel-wrapper {
  border: 5px solid chartreuse;
  position: relative;
}

.panel {
  height: 100vh;
  font-size:10vh;
  color:#fff;
}

.panel-1 { background: aqua; }
.panel-2 { background: blue; }
.panel-3 { background: darkblue; }

.sticky-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  background: transparent;
  top: calc(100vh/2 - 613px/2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 3;
  float:left; /* added */
  shape-outside:linear-gradient(transparent,transparent);
}

.sticky-element {
  width: 315px;
  height: 613px;
  background: yellow;
  top: 0;
}

footer {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight bold;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 250px 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-wrapper">
  <div class="panel-wrapper">
    <div class="sticky-wrapper">
      <div class="sticky-element"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in dignissim magna. Nulla magna lorem, mattis et ultricies euismod, posuere condimentum nulla. Pellentesque mollis, mauris quis elementum porttitor, arcu mauris aliquet metus, sed maximus sapien diam varius est. Aliquam erat volutpat.</div>
    <div class="panel panel-2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in dignissim magna. Nulla magna lorem, mattis et ultricies euismod, posuere condimentum nulla. Pellentesque mollis, mauris quis elementum porttitor, arcu mauris aliquet metus, sed maximus sapien diam varius est. Aliquam erat volutpat.</div>
    <div class="panel panel-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras in dignissim magna. Nulla magna lorem, mattis et ultricies euismod, posuere condimentum nulla. Pellentesque mollis, mauris quis elementum porttitor, arcu mauris aliquet metus, sed maximus sapien diam varius est. Aliquam erat volutpat.</div>
  </div>
  <footer>
     Should not overlap here!
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: that is interesting, can you explain how that works? I get why the position absolute makes troubles but how the float affects the behaviour like this is beyond my understanding

Comment: @Warden330 float:left will remove the element from the flow so it can overlap block elements and won't take space

Comment: Very cool. I was not aware of that. This is very useful in many scenarios, thanks :)

Comment: It wasnt working in my real world use case, came back and you put in the shape-outside and boom that works! Again, something I haven't heard or used before. thank you again!!

Comment: @TemaniAfif this doesn't seem to work on Chrome. Firefox and Safari it does work. Chrome, however, the content is actually floated. Like the sticky wrapper is floated left but taking up 100% width and if I scroll right I see the content that's supposed to be under.

Comment: @OscarGodson the snippet is not working or your code? Actually I am testing in chrome and it's fine for me .. you probably have more CSS involved

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yeah there's more but I can't tell what within that block would be causing it since the DOM structure should be extremely close to what I have there https://codepen.io/oscargodson/pen/LYZEZQL

Comment: Also the footer is huge just to test that it sticks in place :)

Comment: @OscarGodson you are using display:grid which is the culprit .. replace `display:grid` by `width: 100%;
    display: inline-grid;`

Comment: @TemaniAfif ok you've saved me enough times. I bought you 14 coffees :D

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you want this to behave:
You can just make sure the footer overlaps it like this:

```css
footer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 20; /* above z-index of sticky element*/
}
```

Or you can add a little javascript to detect the scroll position and when it is x amount from the bottom, ie footer height, change the css to position absolute.

Comment: Wouldnt the yellow box / phone be cut off then? Not really sticky and remain in the container?

Comment: @OscarGodson Yes you are right it will cut it off. Which is why the javascript solution above maybe better suited to your needs. Even better, use javascript to simply add a class or data attribute onto the sticky element once it reaches scroll position. That way you keep most logic on css.